# Memory allocation of C++ in Ubuntu

Tags: ram, c++

First of all, I'm sorry if the question doesn't belong here. I want to make sure whether this issue has to do something with my Ubuntu.

The C++ code below makes **2621440** integer variables. *Each integer requires **4** bytes from the memory*.  So, **2621440** integers would take (2621440 * 4 =) **10MB** from the virtual memory.

The problem I'm having is, this program occupies nearly **80MB** of memory, for no reason.
I monitored the the memory usage from *System Monitor* and the *top* command as well.

> int main()
>   {
>   int *p;
>   for (int n=0; n < 2621440 ; n++)
>   { p = new int ; }
>   }

I'm on **Kubuntu 13.04 (amd64)**
Please give me a little explanation.
Thanks!

Comment: .......I use g++

Answer (score 1):

*Each integer requires **32 bits** from the memory*.

4 bytes = 4 * 8 bits = 4 bytes, so 2621440 integers would take (2621440 * 4 * 8) bits = (2621440 * 4) bytes = 80 megabits (Mb) = 10 megabytes (MB).

I think that you make a confusion between megabits (Mb) and megabytes (MB): 8 megabits (Mb) = 1 megabytes (MB).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but **top** command in terminal shows memory usage in KiB, which means Kilo Bytes. I think the units are correct. This is so strange...

Comment: @Naveen Not really, KiB means [Kibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte), MiB - mebibyte, GiB - gibibyte and so on.

Comment: Oh, I get it, 1KiB = 1024bytes &  1kB = 1000bytes. Though it doesn't change anything. I'm still stuck with this question x(